# Dispatching an event in Laravel 5 on model created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-spark

I wan to create a Laravel signup system where I would send an email to verify the email once a user has signed up. I tried adding an event dispatched to the created method but I got an error

```
 Fatal error: Non-static method Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher::fire() cannot be called statically
```

Here is what I came up with.

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Laravel\Spark\Teams\CanJoinTeams;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as BaseUser;
use Laravel\Spark\Auth\TwoFactor\Authenticatable as TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as EventDispatcher; 
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Auth\TwoFactor\Authenticatable as TwoFactorAuthenticatableContract;

class User extends BaseUser implements TwoFactorAuthenticatableContract
{
    use Billable, TwoFactorAuthenticatable,CanJoinTeams;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'name',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [

    ];


    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'card_brand',
        'card_last_four',
        'extra_billing_info',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'stripe_id',
        'stripe_subscription'       
    ];

    /**
     * Boot the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($user) {
            $user->token = str_random(30);
        });

        static::created(function ( $user) {        

           EventDispatcher::fire('UserCreated');   

        });
    }


    /**
     * Confirm the user.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function confirmEmail()
    {
        $this->verified = true;
        $this->token = null;

        $this->save();
    }    

}
```

I also tried changing the code to

```
  use Billable, TwoFactorAuthenticatable,CanJoinTeams, EventDispatcher;
```

and replacing the boot part with

```
 static::created(function ( $user, EventDispatcher $event) {        

       $event->fire('UserCreated');   

    });
```

But it gave me another error

```
App\User cannot use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher - it is not a trait
```

How do I fire the event once the model has been created ?

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel >`5.4` and higher, you can associate eloquent event in your Model class to fire a custom event - e.g. `'created' => ProjectCreated::class`. So basically, on Eloquent model `created` fire `ProjectCreated` Event.

```html
class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'client_id'];

    /**
     *
     * Eloquent model events
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => ProjectCreated::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Question: Inside the `ProjectCreated::class` how do I retrieve the current `Project::class` record information?  Is `ProjectCreated` an event or listener?

Answer (score 1):

Model's lifecycle events are fired by Eloquent already so no need to fire them yourself. Event name is created with the following code:

```
$event = "eloquent.{$event}: ".get_class($model);
```

Therefore, if you want to listen on the created event, you need to listen on **"eloquent.created: App\User"**. The event handler will get the related **User** model as one of **handle()** parameters.

If you hovewer want to dispatch an event of your own, you can do that using **Event** facade:

```
Event::fire('UserCreated', $user);
```

You can read more about events in Laravel here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

Comment: Since I am pretty new to Laravel and am not very well aware of the event lifecycle I tried using the Event::fire way but I got an

Fatal error: Class 'App\Event' not found

Do i need to call it elsewhere ?

Comment: Add "use Event;" at the top of your file or call \Event::fire